# Cannot transfer float value from Geometry Nodes to Shader

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using Blender 3.5.1

### What I Want To Achieve

I am creating a Procedural Planet Generator with Geometry Nodes.

For this purpose I prepared two materials - one for the surface (surface) & one for the atmosphere and clouds (volume).

In Geometry Nodes, I generate two spheres and apply the aforementioned materials to them. Each sphere receives its respective material.

Now I would like to drive the generation process entirely through Geometry Node Group Inputs, but most of the variables and colors that can be dialed and changed are located in the **Shader Group Inputs**.

No matter what I try, I simply cannot get float values from Geometry Nodes to the Shader.

### What I Tried

- I tried feeding in the geometry node Group Input values directly to the Group Output and then getting these values in the Shader via the Attribute node (I tried declaring the variable type as Geometry, Instance, etc.) but to no avail. (see picture)

[image: One of the approaches to get the float attribute/field cloudDensity over to the Shader]

- Then I tried it by *Store Named Attribute* which I placed in Geometry Nodes before assigning the material. Then I tried it after setting the material and tried all different ways to store it inside the geometry (points, lines, splines, instance, etc.)
- Then I tried to create the attribute in the *Object Data Properties* but still couldn't receive any values from within the Shader. I made sure that the attribute names are correct and identical.

Now I really ran out of options/ideas and overall patience. All I want is to get a simple float value (field? It seems all Geo Node outputs besides Geometry are fields, no matter what you do) from GeoNodes to Shader.

It cannot be that difficult, can it? All tutorials and related posts I found suggested the above way but none of them worked for me.

EDIT: Here is the Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w491kfe7acgxou/Geometry%20Nodes.blend?dl=0

EDIT 2: I have tried all suggestions from here but it still won't work.
I also tried Blender 3.3 but with the same outcome. It appears as if the Attribute never receives the value from Geometry Node. Its output always equals 0 (NaN).

SOLUTION: Gordons suggestion solved the problem. The solution works as long as I do not plugin the Realize Istance after the Instance of points node.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**//EDIT:** Now that I inspected the material I see where the problem lies - or at least I think it has something to do with what I see there. Within the material's nodegroups you are using 4D textures which of course makes sense, but the attribute value is stored on the surface of the sphere in all vertices. I may be completely wrong here but it led me to a working answer: do not use the *Realize Instances* on the "Atmosphere" geometry and use *Type:* > *Instancer* in the material.

Now you might say this did not work, and that is no wonder: you have no instances. You are adding two *UV Sphere* mesh primitives, but those are not instances. So I would do the following:

**New simpler answer thanks to Gorgious**:

1. Replace the *Realize Instances* nodes in your setup with *Geometry to Instance* nodes. Now you can use the *Type* > *Instancer* on the *Attribute* node in the material shader.

   [image: new nodetree setup]

**Older complicated answer:**

1. Go into *Edit Mode* of your base object, select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*. Now the original base mesh is only a single vertex. Go back to *Object Mode*.
2. Go to the *Geometry Nodes* editor. Unfortunately you have deleted the *Geometry* input, so select the *Group Input* and add a new input, switch the *Type* to *Geometry*. Move it to the top of the list (this is important!).

   [image: add new geometry input]
3. Now add two *Instance on Points* node. Plug the new *Geometry* socket into both of the *Points* inputs. Plug the "Planet" frame's output into one of the *Instance* inputs and the the one from the *Atmosphere* frame into the other. The *Instances* outputs get plugged into the *Join Geometry* node.

   [image: instance on points]
4. With the *Attribute Domain* > *Instance* for the "Cloud Density" output and the *Attribute* node set to *Type* > *Instancer* in the material this should now work as expected, at least for the atmosphere. If the planet for some reason needs its instance to be realized, you can do this before the *Join Geometry* node.

   [image: nodetree setup]

Comment: Okay, I gave your suggestion a try but it still won't work as expected. I appended the blend-file via dropbox link to my initial post if you want to have a look.

Comment: You also need to change the output attribute data type to Mesh https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5fng.png

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Gorgious.
I cannot find the attribute data type Mesh. I tried Point, Edge, Face, Face Corner, Spline and Instance, but none of them showed the expected result.

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat I don't know what "data type Mesh" Gorgious is referring to, but on the _Outputs_ settings you have to switch the _Attribute Domain_ to e.g. _Point_ - which is the default value, that's why it should have worked out-of-the-box. Well, actually anything there would work except for _Spline_ and _Instance_, since you have a mesh there and no curve or instance. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: You're right. You can use Point, Edge, Face or Face Corners which are subdomains of the mesh type. It should work like that, if it doesn't then you've changed something else you're not showing.

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat If it still does not work then it's maybe because you are not aware of the fact that you have disconnected the _Fac_ output from the group node in the shader. At least in the file you have uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, guys. I attached the blend file at my main post, so you can have a look for yourself. No matter what constellation of domains I tried or what way I deliver the attribute to the geo node group putput, the shader attribute node just won't receive it.
Could this be a bug of Blender 3.5.1?

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat See my last comment.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann
Thank you for the heads-up. I was actually aware of that. I only did that, so everyone opening the file would first see what the cloud layer is supposed to look like when the fac is plugged in.
But after plugging it in, the cloud layer just disappears.
Did it work when you plugged in the fac? If yes, which version of Blender were you opening the file with?

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat Sure it disappears. Because it is hidden in a volumetric atmosphere with a density of 50 - the value which you transfer with the attribute. The question was why you don't get the attribute value out - I'm not going to dissect your complex "Atmosphere" group with multiple subgroups to find out why it's not creating a proper cloud layer...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann No need to disect the Shader Node Group (Yeah, it is quite complex) as the Cloud Density value is only used one time in there for the clouds you can see when starting up the Blend file. It won't affect anything else of the whole Shader Group but these clouds. (I made sure of that by testing different inputs for the Shader Group Input Value. Optimal density is 4 but I set it to 50 in the GeoNode Group to make it very obvious once it works. But it seems to resort to a value of 0 when I plug in the fac from the Attribute.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Basically, when you dial the Cloud Density value in the Shader up and down, you can see the effect on the clouds. What I would expect is, that the value fed in via Attribute from GeoNode (50.0f) should create the same effect as if I type in 50 into the Cloud Density manually, but the result is the same as if I type in 0.

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat I've looked into the material shader and now I've edited my answer to hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for taking the time to help me and look into this, Gordon, I really appreciate this!
Did the solution you suggested work on your end? If so, in which Blender version?

I followed your description dilligently, merged the base mesh down to a single vert, changed the node layout and the attribute settings as you suggested and placed the Geometry Input on top, but still get the same result. I start feeling cursed :|

EDIT: YES! It worked! But only if I don't use the Realize Instance nodes after the Instance on Points. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat Well, my new answer states "do not use the Realize Instances" and they are not shown in my setup. I only suggest to maybe use one on the planet, if that material should only work with realized instances (which I didn't test, I focused on the atmosphere).

Comment: For step 3 you can also use the node [Geometry to Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/geometry_to_instance.html) if I followed correctly then you don't need the two instance on points nodes.

Comment: @Gorgious Oh good to know, I didn't know this existed. In that case actually step 1 and 2 are completely unnecessary.